# Is it possible to access a variable from another method?

Tags: java

Have relatively simple code that asks for dimensions of a tic-tac-toe board, along with the requirement for the win condition (how many Xs or Os in a row)

```
public TicTacToe(int aNumRows, int aNumColumns, int aSizeToWin) {

int boardLength = (aNumRows*aNumColumns);
}
```

For the game itself, I wanted to simply make the maximum allowed number of turns be the size of the board.

```
public CellValue nextPlayer() {

for (int i = 0; i<=boardLength.length(); i++){
  if (i%2 == 0){
    System.out.println("X is up");
  }
  else{
    System.out.println("Y is up");
  }
}
```

The error that I get is "Cannot find symbol", since it is not in the same method.

```
symbol:   class boardLength
location: class TicTacToe
```

I was wondering if it's possible to use boardLength in the CellValue method?

Also I apologize for any mistakes in my question, I'm very new and bad at this.

Comment: Is CellValue an inner class in your TicTacToe class?

Comment: create a field called `boardLength`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make `boardLength` an instance variable so it can be accessed by all instance methods of the class.

```
private final int boardLength;
public TicTacToe(int aNumRows, int aNumColumns, int aSizeToWin) {
    this.boardLength = (aNumRows*aNumColumns);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can access the var

1. use it as a filed of `TicTacToe`

```java
public class TicTacToe {
private int boardLength;

//provide getter/setter

}
//then you can access by getter in other class

// here create a TicTacToe instance
TicTacToe tt = new TicTacToe(1,2,3);

for (int i = 0; i<=tt.getBoardLength(); i++){
  if (i%2 == 0){
    System.out.println("X is up");
  }
  else{
    System.out.println("Y is up");
  }
}
```

2. use static field, if the length is shared by multiple thread , make it a static var of class TicTacToe

```java
public class TicTacToe {
 public static volatile boardLength;
}

// then you can access it directly 
for (int i = 0; i<=TicTacToe.boardLength; i++){
  if (i%2 == 0){
    System.out.println("X is up");
  }
  else{
    System.out.println("Y is up");
  }
}
```

You need be aware of the multithreaded problem like dirty data when you use it in multithreaded situation.